# Wait for mongodb save before next

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a list of documents that I need to save on mongoDB, after having executing some process on them.

I have a reactive mongoDB dependency so I would like to use it. I would like to avoid the usage of another dependency (the non reactive one) if possible.
The 2nd document process should begin after the 1st document has been saved.

```
    Mono<List<Index>> deferredCreate = Mono.defer(() -> index
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .flatMapSequential(entity -> {
                            repository.process(entity).subscribe();
                            return entity;
                        })
            )
            .collectList());
```

with

```
   public Mono<IndexDocument> process(Index index) {
          if(someCondition) { return mongoOperations.save(index); }
          else { return mongoOperations.findAndReplace(query, index); }
}
```

Here, the list is process index by index but index n+1 process begins after index n begins and I need it begins after n process is finished.
I cannot put .block() instead of subscriber otherwise I have an error (block cannot be used in parallel stream). I tried with concatMap but this is the same.

Is there any way to do it ?
I use reactive programming because this is part of a larger process that needs to be reactive.

Comment: You don’t need to call ‘subscribe’ explicitly. Replace the inner part with ‘return repository.process(entity).thenReturn(entity)’

Comment: yes I have tried this too, but the issue is the same, number N starts after number N-1 has began and not after it is finished

Comment: Could you share the whole flow? How do you call save?

Comment: sorry this is process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you should not `subscribe` explicitly. `flatMapSequential` will subscribe behind the scene and preserve the original order

```
Mono<List<Index>> deferredCreate = Mono.defer(() -> index
     .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
     .flatMapSequential(entity -> 
             repository.process(entity)
                    .thenReturn(entity)
     )
     .collectList());
```